# kmalloc and slab relationship

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, kmalloc

My understanding about `kmalloc()` is that it uses generic slabs of kernel to allocate memory e.g. *kmalloc-8, kmalloc-16, .. kmalloc-8k*. But after inserting below module I'm not seeing any change to `active_objs` parameter of any `kmalloc-xxx` or `kmalloc-rcl-xx` slabs.

I tried with different memory size e.g. 128, 4096, 512 but no luck.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

char *data;

static int __init start(void)
{ 
        data = kmalloc(2048, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!data) {
                printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to allocate memory\n");
                return -ENOMEM;
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "Module is loaded. (%ld)\n", ksize(data));
        data[0] = 'a';
        return 0;
}

static void __exit end(void)
{
        kfree(data);
        return;
}

module_init(start);
module_exit(end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Output: `Module is loaded. (2048)`

Used `vmstat -m` and `/proc/slabinfo` to monitor slabs active objects.

Kernel version: 5.4.0-135-generic

**Second issue:**

Though I am aware about __GFP_RECLAIM (used in kswapd and direct reclaim).

But struggling to understand difference between `kmalloc-rcl-xx` slabs and `kmalloc-xx` slabs.

Is `kmalloc-rcl-xx` freed memory is reclaimable but `kmalloc-xx` not?

Which slab will be used if we call `kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL)` and why?